# VB.NET How to add a child node to a specific node in treeview

Tags: vb.net, treeview, vb.net-2010

How to add a child node to a specific node in treeview? Say I have "Item1" in treeview already, how do I add "SubItem1" to "Item1" as it's child node?

I know its probably really simple, but i tried lots of stuff, i just cant get it working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Adding child node to parent (non-selected)

First use `Find()` to get a reference to the parent node.  Then add it using the same technique as the other sections below.

```
Dim MyNode() As TreeNode 
MyNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Find("Item1", True)
MyNode(0).Nodes.Add("SubItem1")
```

## Adding nodes programmatically

If you want to add the child nodes to a particluar parent node, the idea is to add the child nodes to their parent node by using the `parent.node.add()` method.
You can create any number of child like this.

**For example if you want to have a scenario like:**

> Grandfather-> Father-> Son

Then you could do this:

```
dim GrandfatherNOde as treenode = tree.nodes.add("Grandfather")
dim fatherNode as treenode = GrandfatherNode.Nodes.add("Father")
dim sonNode as treenode = fatherNode.Nodes.add("Son")
```

## More reading/examples

This page has a good example you can run to dynamically add child nodes to the tree.  They do it on a button, which they've hooked up like this:

```
Private Sub AddChild_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddChild.Click
    TView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(Text1.Text)
End Sub
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11830/The-Basic-Operations-on-using-the-TreeView-Control

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I've included a more complete example.  Let me know if it works for you.  If not, we'll figure out what the problem is from there.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for all these examples, but again the "Grandfather" is already added. what i want to do is add the "Father" to the "Grandfather" without selecting it. I already know how to add all three at the same time. Sorry for sounding like a noob. thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I understand what you're saying. Let me update my post to be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

If you make sure that you assign a [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.name.aspx) to your [`TreeNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bctbxtcb.aspx) You can use [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.TREENODECOLLECTION.FIND%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true) to locate it and add the `Child` node.

Example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Nodes(5) As TreeNode


    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        Nodes(0) = New TreeNode("Root")
        Nodes(0).Name = "Root"
        Nodes(1) = New TreeNode("Item1")
        Nodes(1).Name = "Item1"
        Nodes(2) = New TreeNode("Item2")
        Nodes(2).Name = "Item2"
        Nodes(3) = New TreeNode("Item3")
        Nodes(3).Name = "Item3"
        Nodes(4) = New TreeNode("Item4")
        Nodes(4).Name = "Item4"
        Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(Nodes(1))
        Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(Nodes(2))
        Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(Nodes(3))
        Nodes(0).Nodes.Add(Nodes(4))

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(Nodes(0))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim tmpNode() As TreeNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Find("Item1", True)
        'Assuming only one Match
        tmpNode(0).Nodes.Add("Child Of Item1")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing when i got here, and so far i couldnt get to what i needed.

So i got to this page: http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/168335-How-add-node-treeview-VB.NET.aspx

Really cool and simple to do after you give it a look.

It turn out that we only need to keep typing nodes.add("nodename") to keep adding sublevels.
Treeview1.Nodes.Add("Root_1").Nodes.Add("Child_Level_1").Nodes.Add("Child_Level_2")

```
Treeview1.Nodes.Add("Root_1").Nodes.Add("Child_Level_1").Nodes.Add("Child_Level_2")
```

This would get something like:

http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/7254/semttulonzk.jpg

Hope it Helped ;D.

Answer (score 1):

*Assumes empty TreeView:

```
Dim rootNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Root")

rootNode.Nodes.Add("SubNode")
```